# Can psql output a description of all tables, but only tables?

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I do `\d public.*` I get a list of descriptions of tables, but also of all other indices etc.

When I do `\dt public.*` I get a list of tablenames, but not the full descriptions of those tables.

Is there a command that gives me the full descriptions of all tables without the other object types?

Version used: `psql --version` outputs `psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `obj_description()` for that:

```
select tbl.relname as table_name, 
       obj_description(tbl.oid) as comment
from pg_class tbl
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = tbl.relnamespace
where n.nspname = 'public' 
  and tbl.relkind = 'r' ;
```